# Find Duplicate Values in 2 Columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The title isn't strictly accurate: I'm not *just* trying to find "duplicate" records; I'm trying to find all records that have a duplicate value in one column, but only if all of those records also have a duplicate value in another column.

As a real world problem, it's phrased this way: I want a list of all items for which every size of that item has the same status code.

Some example data:

table `catalog_items`

```
id, name
 0, Gloves
 1, Spade
 2, Seed
```

table `catalog_sizes`

```
id, f_id,  size, price, status
 0,    0, small,     1,  oos
 1,    0,   med,     2,  oos
 2,    0, large,     3,
 3,    1,   one,    12,  oos
 4,    1,   two,    20,  oos
 5,    2,   1oz,    10,  bo
 6,    2,   1lb,   100,  bo
```

(Note that `id` 2 *aka large gloves* is not `oos` like it's two smaller sizes.)  In our real data, all items will have at least 1 size, and most have 3-5.  Also, our data set will never be larger than 10,000 records.

This get's close:

```
SELECT f_id, status
FROM catalog_sizes 
WHERE status != ''
GROUP BY f_id, status
```

but isn't correct because it also returns a record for items that have *some* sizes with duplicate status.  (e.g. `f_id` 0 has two sizes with status `oos`)  I need to get a list of items for which *all* sizes have the same status. Given the example data in `catalog_sizes`, my desired output is:

```
f_id, status
   1,  oos
   2,  bo
```

What's the best way to do this?  Can it be done in a single query?

Comment: Do you `GROUP BY id` or `BY f_id`?

Comment: And you data shows that all `f_id` have more than one size. I don't get why `1` and `2` should be returned and not `0`.

Comment: this @ypercube ... or the count of f_id with same values ordered by status.

Comment: @ypercube edited SQL to correctly `GROUP BY f_id`.  Also, `id` 3 has `f_id` 0 and has a different `status` than it's two other sizes.

Comment: so youre doing the count(*) to figure out the number of times the status appears?

Comment: should be no need to actually count number of times status appears, just that all statuses for a given group are the same...my answer solves this I believe...

Comment: @JohnRuddell sorry, `count(*)` was left over from previous attempts; I edited it out.

Comment: Please mark a correct answer if you were satisfied with a solution

Comment: @SS781 I'm working on it again today.  Both answers work on the test data, but wasn't working perfectly in my real data.  I'm tracking that down now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query should do what you want. it compares the highest and lowest strings (to see if they are different) returns 0 if true so when its only 0 it will appear in query.
see working [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f4f04/17)

```
SELECT f_id, status, COUNT(id)
FROM catalog_sizes
GROUP BY f_id
HAVING STRCMP(MIN(status), MAX(status)) = 0
```

Comment: I didnt just copy what you did. I was building a fiddle and wrote a query? thnx for the post though.

Comment: well I mean you did, but I have seen a lot of this on SO, so I don't blame you...

Comment: my query is almost the same as the OP's query, just because your having is similar to mine doesn't mean i copied it.. ive used that exact method many times.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell.  I wouldn't have understood the idea between the MIN/MAX calls w/o your explanation.

Comment: the max of a list will never be the same as the min if there are more than one diff values in the list. max will always be same as min if there is only one value

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following should work:

```
select ci.name, cs.f_id, MIN(cs.status) AS status
from catalog_items ci join catalog_sizes cs on ci.id = cs.f_id
group by ci.name, cs.f_id
having max(cs.status) = min(cs.status);
```

Le me know if this helps!

Comment: +1 because it''s probably the most efficient way, if there is an index to use. The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 1` would work too, but not so efficiently.

Comment: Ah right, the way I had it should still function fine in MySQL, since it allows you to select a non-grouped column wihtout the need to aggregate on it, but thanks @ypercube for the edit, since it makes the SQL statement more universally compliant!

Comment: @SS781 it also makes it work under any MySQL setting.